# Can no longer migrate traffic in AppEngine flex VM

Tags: google-app-engine

Up until this morning I was able to migrate appengine traffic to different versions of my appengine app. I am now getting an error when I try and do this. Both the console and the command prevent me from migrating traffic. Is this a bug or intentional?

```
cloud app versions migrate master15166002                                                                                    Migrating all traffic from version [default/master15141296] to [default/master15166002]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.migrate) Issues migrating all traffic of service(s): [default]

INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid request.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Traffic migration does not support Managed VMs.
    field: service
  - description: Traffic cannot be migrated to a version with basic or manual scaling.
    field: service.split.allocations[master15141296]
  - description: Traffic migration does not support Managed VMs.
    field: service
  - description: Traffic cannot be migrated to a version with basic or manual scaling.
    field: service.split.allocations[master15166002]
  - description: Warmup requests must be enabled for all versions that will gain additional
      traffic as a result of the traffic migration.
    field: service.split.allocations[master15166002]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the old Managed VMs environment that was deprecated over a year ago (Nov 15, 2016). The [shutdown date was December 15th](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#beta_shutdown_schedule). This same page has information for how to upgrade your application from the old (and deprecated) Managed VM beta.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a bug with the API/Console. It fixed itself a day later.